How can I get a list of Azure SQL database backups using az cli?
I am trying to get a list of Azure database backups and am using the following
az sql db backup list --resource-group "MyRG" 
       --server "<myservvername>.database.windows.net" 
       --database-name "MyDb" --query '[0].id' --output tsv

but I get an error:

ERROR: 'backup' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

How can I get a list of these backups using az cli?

Not in a position to test right now, but you'll note that az sql db doesn't have a backup command.

Azure does routine backups . So looking at the command which can i use to give me the last full backup of the database ? I want to be able to download to a local drive using az cli ?

You can't download them.

so then need to Export ?

Create a bacpac.
